# HTML5 Drag file from one box to another. not working properly

Tags: javascript, css, html

Having a problem. Once I drop the image into the left box, it doesnt display.
This is what happens:
Before i drag the image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6JSM.png
After I drag the image. it doesnt display. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Du0c.png

the error on chrome says:

GET file:///C:/%22test Dropped
angelo.js:42
leftbox.innerHTML=e.dataTransfer.getData('text');

Here is my HTML

```
 <!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>angelos site</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
   <script src="angelo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <section id="leftbox">
      i dare you to drop an image inme.
   </section>
   <section id="rightbox">
      <img id="facepic" src="C:\test\face.png">
   </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my JS.

```
function doFirst(){

   mypic=document.getElementById('facepic');//tell js to recognize facepic.
   mypic.addEventListener("dragstart",startDrag,false);//when you start dragging facepic run startDrag function. "dragstart" is keyword in java that recognizes when you start dragging an object.

   leftbox=document.getElementById('leftbox'); //tell js to recognize leftbox.
   leftbox.addEventListener("dragenter",function(e){e.preventDefault();},false);//make same for all browsers.need to override. we arent using this.
   leftbox.addEventListener("dragover",function(e){e.preventDefault();},false);//make same for all browsers.need to override. we arent using this.
   leftbox.addEventListener("drop",dropped,false);//call function dropped.

}

function startDrag(e){
   var code='<img src="C:\test\face.png">';
   e.dataTransfer.setData('Text',code);
}
```

Here is my CSS

```
#leftbox{
   float:left;
   width:250px;
   height:250px;
   margin:5px;
   border:3px solid blue;
}

#rightbox{
   float:left;
   width:250px;
   height:250px;
   margin:5px;
   border:3px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work fine for me, though, I'm just guessing what your `dropped` method looks like in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/aVrB4/

From above you can see your JS is probabl OK. I'm guessing that your browser isn't liking the local links. Try `file:///c:/test/face.png` for those img's src attributes, or just use relative paths.